# How to add numbers with same base but unknown exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm taking a university math course despite knowing better. Among the straightforward problems I encountered the following:

Simplify:

$$5^x +5^{x+2}$$

The answer is supposed to be $26*5^x$

How am I supposed to arrive at this conclusion, do I interpret this as some kind of short geometric sum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$5^{x}+5^{x+2}=5^{x}+5^{x}\cdot 5^{2}=5^{x}(1+5^{2})=5^{x}\cdot 26$

Comment: I didn't understand that last step, why can $5^x(1+5^2) $ be written as $5^x*26$?

Comment: Because $5^2=25$

Comment: ahh allright I guess I'm just tired today.